# Load Data Infile on MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I have a "load data" command that executes just fine, but I need to modify it to remove most of the fields from a CSV.  I believe I've put it together correctly, but form some reason MySQL says that the syntax is not correct.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file' INTO TABLE cdr_records (@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
dateTimeOrigination, 
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
callingPartyNumber, 
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
originalCalledPartyNumber, 
finalCalledPartyNumber, 
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
pkid,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
duration, 
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy,
@dummy) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES;
```

I get;

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LIN' at line 104
```

Comment: The columns list goes after all the options, I believe. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file' INTO TABLE cdr_records 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES
(@dummy, ..., @dummy) ;
```

instead. First the FIELD and LINES clause then the list of the columns, not the other way around.

The syntax of [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) is:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

Comment: thank you, that was the problem.  Not sure why the solutiions I read said otherwise, but your answer did the trick.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Put your terminators and other options first

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file' INTO TABLE cdr_records
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 2 LINES
(@dummy,
@dummy,
...
```